# different order across browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an object of values as a response to $.get

```
 $.get('www.example.com/get-data/', {'data': $('form').serialize()}, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key,value);
            });
...
```

I'm facing different order on different devices = on desktop Safari 8.0 it returns me the following order:

```
10 R10
15 R15
16 R16
```

But it returns reversed order on mobile safari (iOS 6)

```
16 R16    
15 R15
10 R10
```

Does anybody know why?
I've also tried to sort returned object:

```
> data
Object {10: "R10", 15: "R15", 16: "R16"}
> data.sort()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Do you know how to sort this object to keep alphabetical order on all devices? 
I need to keep "key => value" definition is there any other way then using an array of objects? For example

```
[{10:"R10"},{15:"R15"},{16:"R16"}]
```

Comment: Objects have no order.

Comment: I don't think you can sort an object by keys. But why is the other important? You can have an array of sorted keys, but that's not efficient.

Comment: JSON by definition has no real order and while most browsers respect the order as specified in source, there's no guarantee that all will.

Comment: Here a *"JSON sorter"* : http://jsfiddle.net/NHzxR/